# Pandas: How to find items in a column that are not in another column (Excel)

Tags: pandas, excel, dataframe

I have two Excel workbooks:

`w_runnable.xlsx` (sheet name: my_list):

[image]

`w_results.xlsx` (sheet name: my_list):

[image]

Q: How can I write a code that finds items on `w_results.xlsx` column "Item" that are NOT in `w_runnable.xlsx`and. And also the other way around, find items on `w_runnable.xlsx` column "Item" that are NOT in `w_results.xlsx` and puts all this in a new workbook `differences.xlsx`

new workbook `differences.xlsx`:

[image]

Here's my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd

w_results = 'w_results.xlsx'
w_runnable = 'w_runnable.xlsx'

df_results_mylist = pd.read_excel(w_results, sheet_name='my_list')
df_runnable_mylist = pd.read_excel(w_runnable, sheet_name='my_list')


print(df_results_mylist)
print(df_runnable_mylist)
```